# callback location does not get called after document signed using RightSignature API

Tags: c#, api, document, callbackurl

When I send a one-off document to RightSignature via their API, I'm specifying a callback location in the XML document as specified in RightSignature's schema definition. I then get a signer-link value back from their API for the document. I display the HTML response from the signer-link URL in an iFrame on our website. When our user signs the document in this iFrame, which is rendering the responses from their website, I want their website to post to our callback location.

Can I do this with the RightSignature API and does it make sense?

So far, I'm only getting content in the iFrame that indicates that the signing was successful. The callback location does not seem to be getting called.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal, i got it solved just now. Basically, i was doing two things wrong first you have to go in RightSignature Account and set it there the CallBack url

Account > Settings > Advanced Settings

But the thing which RS is unable to mention to us that this url can not be on localhost, but it should be of https i mean like Live URL.

And then in your CallBack just write these two lines and it has the complete XML which we would have the GUID and document status as well.

byte[] data = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);
string callBackXML = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Hope this will help the World using RS :)